# Environment variables undefined in Next.js Project

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

I have been stabbing at this for the past hour and it is driving me insane. I am trying to access a variable from .env.local in my Next.js project, but it is undefined.

I have attempted the below:

- Restarting server
- Clearing .next folder and node_modules
- Console logging (process.env) - returns {}
- Using NEXT_PUBLIC_, but my key is sensitive so i dont want that
- Adding env to next.config.js

The main issue arose in an API call which I have in pages/api/fetchRequest.ts. I am calling this in a component, AiNewTask which is passed to page.tsx in app/. After this wasn't working I tried doing a simple console log in my page.tsx file and that didn't work either.

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
 env: {
    OPENAI_API_KEY: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
   },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```